# Android app jdk 1.6 to 1.7 errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'am writing android application with couple activities in eclipse. I have one object in MainActivity and I want it to be visible in all others activities, so i've made it:

```
public static cPlayer player = new cPlayer();
```

and when I do:

```
switch (MainActivity.player.getName())
```

I have error:

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted
```

And it want to change JRE to 1.7. So i do it. But after that i have another error:

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

But after that, the previous problem returns.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java switch statement didn't support `String`.

Up through `Java 6` you could only evaluate primitive variable such as floats, longs, boolean, Integers and so on...

That changed with the `Java Version 7`.

However that is not the default SDK that comes with android.

If you want to use these features you'll need to use the `Java 7 Developers` Kit from Oracle.